# Haskell: How to capture keyboard press like up, down, left and right

Tags: haskell, keyboard-events

I am planning to create a game using haskell, but cannot figure out the way to capture key events like pressing up, down, left and right on keyboard.
I tried getChar but it does not capture these. (or probably i am not aware how it does)

Also it would be great to capture CTRL, ALT combinations as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asynchronous keyboard IO is OS-specific, so you'd need a library to abstract that.

As to the "processing" part of it, such libraries usually allow you to register callbacks for the events. From them, you can for example use `TQueue` from `STM` to push the events onto, and then process them sequentially in your pure code.

[GLFW-b demo](https://github.com/bsl/GLFW-b-demo/blob/master/src/Main.hs) has a pretty nice example of that technique in practice. If you want to create a text game, it would probably be an overkill to pull a whole thing for that; maybe look for some ncurses binding?